# Rails PgBouncer client_idle_timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql, pgbouncer

my problem is a pgbouncer which is dropping connections. Sysadmin set the **client_idle_timeout** to 60 seconds. Is there any solve on rails side for this? I mean, is there a possibility (a gem, or settings) to connect and drop connection (reconnection) to database every query we want to send ?

ruby 2.0.0
rails 4.2.3
pg 0.17.1

Im getting following error when connection is longer than x seconds (for example when I open rails console, wait x seconds and then run some ActiveRecord query to db):

> ERROR:  client_idle_timeout
>   Contract Load (0.5ms)  SELECT 
>   "contracts".* FROM "contracts"  ORDER BY "contracts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
>   PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed
>   unexpectedly : 
> SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts"  ORDER BY
>   "contracts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
>  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed
>   unexpectedly : 
> SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts"  ORDER BY
>   "contracts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Yeah, I ran into a similar issue, the problem is the idle timeout configured, you have to increase it otherwise you cannot do anything in the console. You can do a huge try/catch when rails executes the queries and tries to reconnect with active record manually after the connection is gone.

Comment: @MaicolBen its not a fix. About those two I knew. I was looking for a fix for this than a runaround. Like for example reconnecting every time this happens or something.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` will return the stale connections back into the thread pool and check out fresh connections so you don't have to restart your console/server